# Webpack with TypeScript - When targeting to ES6 the import keywork isn't define

Tags: typescript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs, ts-loader

I'm working on a new Angular2 project with Webpack as the model loader, and Typescript as the development language.

When I target the Typescript compiler to target to ES5 everything works fine.
But When I target to ES6 and added `babel-loader` as the trasplier to ES5 I'm getting the error: `Unexpected token import`

**Working ES5 configuration:**

```
// tsconfig.json
"compilerOptions":
{
    "target": "es5",
    // ..
}

// webpack.config.js   
module:
    {
        loaders:
        [
            { test: /\.tsx?$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "ts-loader" },
            { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel-loader" },
            // ...
        ]
    }

// app.ts
import 'core-js' // this line is transpiled by ts-comiler/loader to 'require('core-js')'
```

**Not Working ES6 configuration:**

```
// tsconfig.json
"compilerOptions":
{
    "target": "es6",
    // ..
}

// webpack.config.js   
module:
    {
        loaders:
        [
            { test: /\.tsx?$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel-loader!ts-loader" },
            { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel-loader" },
            // ...
        ]
    }

// app.ts
import 'core-js' // this line throw the error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

I can't understand why the ES6 import keyword is not define??? 
I also notice that if I change the import statement to require() statement then I don't get the error, but I want to use the ES6 import syntax.

Comment: Because Webpack currently doesn't support ES6 import/export. [Webpack 2](https://webpack.github.io/docs/roadmap.html) is still in version beta. Maybe you [can try to use it?](http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2016/10/moving-to-webpack-2/)?

Comment: Indeed webpack1 doesn't support ES6 modules, but this is why I use babel-loader. Babel need to convert my ES6 import/export to something the ES5 browser can handle. Is that make any sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finely I found the answer. When using `babel-loader` you will need not only install `babel-loader` and `babel-core`, but also `babel-preset-es2015` module.

**1. Run shell/terminal commands:** 
`$ npm i babel-loader -D`
`$ npm i babel-core -D`
`$ npm i babel-preset-es2015 -D`
(`npm i` is alias for `npm install`. `-D` is alias for `--save-dav` which will add the packages to the `devDependencies` node in package.json file)

**2. Edit the webpack.config file:**

```
// webpack.config.js   
module:
    {
        loaders:
        [
            { 
                test: /\.tsx?$/, 
                exclude: /node_modules/, 
                loader: "babel-loader?presets[]=es2015!ts-loader" 
            },
            { 
                test: /\.js$/, 
                exclude: /node_modules/, 
                loader: "babel-loader",
                query:
                {
                    presets: ['es2015']
                }
            },
            // ...
        ]
    }
```

For more info, on how to config `ts-loader` with `babel-loader` see: https://gist.github.com/nojaf/daf886031072b572bc9a